# poemscol verseindent "Undefined control sequence."

Tags: poemscol

"\verseindent" always gives me "Undefined control sequence."
How can I fix this?
Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=4.375in, height=7.0in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{poemscol}

\begin{document}
\poemtitle{Title}
\attribution{Author}
\begin{poem}
line one \verseline
\verseindent line two
\end{poem}
\end{document}
```

gives:

```
$ pdflatex test-vi.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

...

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
\\verseindent [#1]->\ifthenelse
                                {\equal {#1}{}}{\hspace {\verseindentamount ...
l.13 \verseindent l
                   ine two
?
```

Comment: `\ifthenelse` is defined by `ifthen` package so add `\usepackage{ifthen}`

Comment: the package ought to load ifthen itself

Comment: Pass David Carlisle's comment onto the author of the `poemscol` package.

Comment: Nice! Adding `\usepackage{ifthen}` fixes it. Also, I just found out it works, without adding `ifthen`, when I load the tex file in the gui, TeXShop, but not when I use the command line.

Comment: texshop is just the editor you can not get different errors, are you sure it is not simply hiding the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\ifthenelse` is defined by `ifthen` package so add `\usepackage{ifthen}` (Thissould be reported to the `poemscol` author, the package could load `ifthen` itself.